# Web service windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services

On adding web service reference from wsdl, the service client class generated is duplexclientbase instead of clientbase. In other projects it is clientbase. Can you suggest a way so that the autogenerated service client will be clientbase. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the client inherits from DuplexClientBase instead of ClientBase. If you want to change the generated code you need to change the implementation of the proxy.

If you want to learn more specifically about one way and duplex binding you can read this article:
http://www.cnblogs.com/chucklu/p/4728528.html